# AngularJS Help Binding Form Inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS/WebDev in general and looking for the best method to proceed with an issue I'm facing.

I have any array of data that is populating a drop down list on a form via ng-options. (Example below)

```
 $scope.products = [
   { name: 'ALD', data1: 'ALDdata', data2: 'ALDdata2', data3: 'ALDdata3' },
   { name: 'BLD', data1: 'BLDdata', data2: 'ALDdata2', data3: 'ALDdata3' },
   { name: 'ELD', data1: 'ELDdata', data2: 'ALDdata2', data3: 'ALDdata3' }
  ],
```

Once an option is chosen by the user, how would I go about binding each of it's properties to individual text boxes.

```
<input type="text" value="{{data1}}" />
<input type="text" value="{{data2}}" />
<input type="text" value="{{data3}}" />
```

I've been stuck on this for nearly 4 hours and endless google searches turned up no relevant results. I very much appreciate any help in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I have found a working JSFiddle of a solution to my problem, however, it is utilizing an older version of AngularJS. Could someone please help me make this work in 1.2.2?

http://jsfiddle.net/n7ZCg/3/

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, i do not think that will work in my case. I have included a jsfiddle to show you what I have currently. http://jsfiddle.net/cmill02s/e8d6n/7/, to reiterate, I'm trying to send each of the values to an individual text box.

Answer (score 1):

The `$scope.products` is a array of values , So you need to `ng-repeat` for that , It's like a foreach 
so try this below way

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="product in products"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="product.data1" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="product.data2" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="product.data3" />
   </li>
 </ul>
```

or try it, This below code display first index of array value.

```
<input type="text" value="{{products[0].data1}}" />
<input type="text" value="{{products[0].data2}}" />
<input type="text" value="{{products[0].data3}}" />
```

Comment: You'll need to remove those braces in the first example (but not the second) - see http://plnkr.co/edit/UuytpblqCcYGKPHVZm05

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for ng-model:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.text

In your example, you want:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data1" />
<input type="text" ng-model="data2" />
<input type="text" ng-model="data3" />
```

Note the lack of braces; you're naming a scope member, not having its value substituted into place.